# how to test if Trim and Replace Method was used

Tags: vb.net, replace, trim

I want the user to enter a password. I don't want the user to include any spaces

Simple solution might be this:

```
password = Console.ReadLine().Replace(" ", "")
```

However, if spaces have been removed, I want to tell the user that it was necessary to remove them.  But, how do I do this?? How can I tell if replace did anything?

Comment: Store the user input to a variable and then compare???

Comment: Don't put everything in one line.

Comment: @Plutonix Actually, that solved the problem - thank you. It doesn't half help to know a bunch of useful methods. Thank you kindly!  I just couldn't think of how to get some sort of boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the strings in variables:

```
Dim password As String = Console.ReadLine()
Dim cleanedPassword  As String = password.Replace(" ", "")
Dim passwordWasDirty As Boolean = cleanedPassword.Length <> password.Length

If passwordWasDirty Then
     ' tell the user....
End If
```